# Mapping Items from Array to arguments in function call

Tags: javascript

Say I have an array of arrays(key/value) that are dynamically generated:

```
var parameters = [ ['Key1','value1'],['key2','value2'],['key3','value3']];
```

and I have a function that accepts a dynamic amount of arguments via the arguments object

```
function somefunction(){
    var args = [];
    var len = arguments.length
    for(var i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        args[i] = arguments[i];
    }
```

How do I call the function with parameters variable so that each item in the array is considered an argument example:

```
somefunction(['Key1','value1'],['key2','value2'],['key3','value3']);
```

instead of:

```
somefunction([['Key1','value1'],['key2','value2'],['key3','value3']]);
```

which is what

```
somefunction(parameters);
```

sends

Comment: Read about [`Function.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

Comment: @manikantgautam https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) :

```
somefunction.apply(null, parameters);
```

If you can use ES6, the [rest operator `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) will works too:

```
somefunction(...parameters);
```

Comment: sadly I couldn't use the rest operator as I need to maintain compatibility with IE, but the apply works